# Where clause to determine if element value is in a sequence (XQ)

Tags: xquery

I am trying to pull some data from our XML-native db, IF the value of one element is in contained sequence of values. Don't think I worded that right. For example,

Given the following XML:

```
<root>
   <a>1</a>
<root>
```

Seems there should be a way to do something like (excuse syntax, treat as pseudo)

```
where root/a in (1,2,3,4)
```

From all of my searching, that doesn't seem to be possible. At best, I've gotten:

```
where root/a = 1 or root/1 = 2 or root/a = 3   etc
```

is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use `=` operator :

```
where root/a = (1,2,3,4)
```

`=` works on set values similar to *contains*, which is what you needed exactly. Contrast `=` with `eq` which requires atomic values for comparison.

---

Below is a complete example.

**XML:**

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <a>1</a>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <a>4</a>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <a>10</a>
    </parent>
</root>
```

**XQuery :**

```
for $p in /root/parent
where $p/a = (1,2,3,4)
return $p
```

**Output :**

```
<parent>
   <a>1</a>
</parent>
<parent>
   <a>4</a>
</parent>
```

demo : [`xpathtester`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/145c74b070959e78acc748550d8f8b63)

Comment: +1 FYI - @tenwest you can also move the filtering from the `where` expression from your FLWOR into a predicate and select the parent elements with this (equivalent and shorter) XPath expression: `/root/parent[a = (1,2,3,4)]`